# jaggery server remote debug in windows

Tags: debugging, wso2

I tried to follow document below to debug a jaggery in windows, but the debug port is not opened, and I cannot remote debug the jaggery application.

Can somebody tell me is it caused by Windows?

BTW, the debug parameter is not like how I debug other wso2 product, like

wso2server.bat -debug 5000.

When trying to debug jaggery, the parameter according to document is 
server.bat -DjdDebug=5000

But there is no impact on starting server.
http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/05/jaggery-debugger/

Answer (score 1):

I have made it work now. Should add the below line when starting the server,

> -DjsDebug=5005

then it will hit the breakpoint line.